# How to read/write external USB storage on Android?

Tags: android, usb, storage, usb-otg

I am currently making an app that needs to be able to read from and write to a USB flash drive connected via a USB OTG adapter. Is there an easy way to access this storage via standard `Java.io.File` APIs? This app is only going to be run on a rooted Motorola Xoom running Android 4.2.2. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android detect usb storage for kitkat (4.4)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208297/android-detect-usb-storage-for-kitkat-4-4).  There I posted solutions for pre-6.0 and 6.0/above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

USB Drives get mounted to your device just like an SDCard does essentially*.

The mount path usually resides at:

> /storage/usb0/

I have not used this on many devices other then my Droid running CyanogenMod, your device may very. You can smiply use a file manager to explore this path. The directories will still exist even if there is no mount path, so you will be able to determine the path.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly with a small modification. For future reference of anyone viewing this thread, the path for a Moto Xoom is `/storage/usbdisk0/`.

Comment: Is not there any method that returns its exact path on every device?